# Responsive JavaScript: Attempts to Fire Functions based on Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery

Third day I'm trying to implement media queries in JavaScript.

Say function A() can be called only if (min-width: 768px),
and the function B() can be called only if (max-width: 767px).

This is easily achieved by using MediaQueryList object. But problems occur with browser resizing.

1. A function A() can not be called if the page was loaded on
   (max-width: 767px), and then resizing to (min-width: 768px).
2. A function A() fires multiple times on click if I try call function on window resize.

I have tried different solutions:

- using addListener
- enquire.js
- setTimeout / clearTimeout — http://go.shr.lc/1kGNpM6

etc

But obviously my knowledge of JavaScript is not enough to do things write. Please help

```
    // Attempt #1  -----------------------------------------------------------------

function responsiveFunction(){
    if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        $('.btn').click(function(event) {
            // Knock knock
        });
    }
}

$(function(){
    responsiveFunction();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    responsiveFunction();
});

// Attempt #2  -----------------------------------------------------------------

function responsiveFunction(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        $('.btn').click(function(event) {
            // Knock knock
        });
    }
}
 
var mql = window.matchMedia('min-width: 768px'); // MQL for MediaQueryList object
 
mql.addListener(responsiveFunction); // Execute responsive function on resize
 
responsiveFunction(mql); // Execute responsive function on load

// Attempt #3  -----------------------------------------------------------------
var smartResize = (function() {
    var timers = {};
    return function(callback, ms, uniqueId) {
        if (!uniqueId) {
            uniqueId = 'Don\'t call this twice without a uniqueId';
        }
        if (timers[uniqueId]) {
            clearTimeout(timers[uniqueId]);
        }
        timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();


function responsiveFunction() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
        $('.btn').click(function(event) {
            // Knock knock
        });
    }
}

// Execute responsive function on load
responsiveFunction();

// Execute responsive function on resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    smartResize(function() {
        responsiveFunction();
    }, 500, 'myUniqueId');
});

// Attempt #4 w enquire.min.js ---------------------------------------------

enquire.register('(min-width: 768px)', {
    match: function() {
        $('.btn').click(function(event) {
            // Knock knock
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function(event) {
        if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
            // Only run the code if media query matches
        }
    });
});
```

Register the `click` handler without checking the `max-width` and check the `width` just before you run the code, if the `width` condition matches then run the code otherwise doesn't run the code.

Comment: WereWolf, under the rules of the StackExchange I can not thank in the comments, so I will say just 'cool' :)

And it would be very nice if you tell how to use width check inside .hover event.